# Android Studio v1.0 generates code with support libs

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android and to Android Studio, which I downloaded recently (version 1.0). Every time I create a new project with for example a "Navigation Drawer Activity" it automatically sets up the code with the use of support libs (*android.support.v7*.app and *android.support.v4.app*). WHY IS THAT??? I want to develop for the SDK 19 and above and NOT to do backwards compatible code.

Is there a way to explicitly say that don't wanna write backwards compatible code during the process of creating a new activity?

Also the default theme is the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">-->
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Again, supporting the compatible theme! Why? I want to use the new themes as Holo!

Of course I can go and rewrite all of the generated code, but it's very inconvenient

Comment: do you know that right now with the new API 21 you need the support and AppCompat another time?

Comment: if you want to use the Nav Drawer you need the support library

Comment: Use the command line to create your project: `android create project --path CriminalIntent --activity CrimeActivity --name CriminalIntent --package com.itch.android.criminalintent --target 1`

Answer (score 1):

Use the command line to create your project:

```
android create project --path CriminalIntent --activity CrimeActivity --name CriminalIntent --package com.itch.android.criminalintent --target 1
```

To find the target:

```
android list targets | grep id
```

And finally import your project with the Android Studio IDE.

In order to use the `android` command, you must add the `<android-sdk-path>/tools` directory to your current `PATH` variable.

You can check this site for reference: http://zetcode.com/mob/android/intro/